# Cant pull data from three tables with query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to write MySQL query to retrieve data from three different tables that have no defined relationship between them.

`FacebookMusicStars` has the names of celebrities from Facebook.

`TwitterMusicStars` has the names of celebrities from Twitter.

`YouTubeMusicStars` has the names of celebrities from YouTube.

The problem is I cant match them in same table by name because their names are 70% not same in all three tables. Query I used:

```
SELECT f.musicNameFacebook
     , t.musicNameTwitter
     , y.musicNameYoutube
  FROM facebookmusicstars f
  LEFT 
  JOIN twittermusicstars t
    ON f.musicNameFacebook LIKE t.musicNameTwitter
  LEFT 
  JOIN youtubemusicstars y
    ON f.musicNameFacebook LIKE y.musicNameYoutube
LEFT JOIN youtubemusicstars ON facebookmusicstars.musicNameFacebook LIKE youtubemusicstars.musicNameYoutube
```

[image]

Comment: I see no problem here. Or are you after a 'FULL JOIN' (or MySQL's emulation of same)

Comment: You can use [TEXT_SEARCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) but there isnt a easy way to find partial/similar match and usually need human intervention to determinate if the match is the correct one

Comment: I don't think `LIKE` does what you think it does...  `'a' LIKE 'á'` is FALSE but `'abc' LIKE '%b%'` is TRUE.  `LIKE` enables you to use `%` and `_` wildcards.

Comment: @MatBailie Surely that depends on the collation ?!?!

Comment: If we don't know what's in the database (nor the rules for extraction), we can't really help you extract it.

Comment: Have you tried soundex?

Answer (score 0):

I use the windows command line and MySQL 5.5 - which don't seem to play together very nicely when it comes to charsets. Using PowerCMD and Latin1, I can get the following, but if you want to account for other characters ('@' etc.) then you'll need to code for that explicitly...

```
SET names latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS facebookmusicstars;
CREATE TABLE facebookmusicstars 
(musicNameFacebook VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS twittermusicstars;
CREATE TABLE twittermusicstars 
(musicNameTwitter VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS youtubemusicstars;
CREATE TABLE youtubemusicstars 
(musicNameYoutube VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO facebookmusicstars VALUES
('Rihanna'), 
('Eminem'), 
('Shakira'), 
('Pitbull'), 
('Beyoncé'), 
('Wiz Khalifa'), 
('Adele'), 
('Bruno Mars'), 
('Ed Sheeran'), 
('MattyBRaps'), 
('Jason Derulo'), 
('Drake'), 
('MALUMA'), 
('Flo Rida'), 
('Usher'), 
('AKON'), 
('Michel Teló'), 
('Nelly'), 
('INNA'), 
('Farruko'), 
('Ciara'), 
('Trey Songz'), 
('Kesha'), 
('Anitta'), 
('Tyga');

INSERT INTO twittermusicstars VALUES
('Rihanna'), 
('Eminem'), 
('Shakira'), 
('pitbull'), 
('Beyonce'), 
('Adèle'), 
('50 Cent'), 
('Lil Wayne'), 
('Ne-yo'), 
('Drake'), 
('Snoop Dogg'), 
('FettyWap'), 
('Usher'), 
('Akon'), 
('Tyga');

INSERT INTO youtubemusicstars VALUES
('Eminem'), 
('Shakira'), 
('Pitbull'), 
('beyonce'), 
('Wiz Khalifa'), 
('Adele'), 
('Bruno Mars'), 
('Ed Sheeran'), 
('MattyBRaps'), 
('Jason Derulo'), 
('Drake'), 
('Maluma'), 
('Flo Rida'), 
('Usher'), 
('Akon'), 
('Michel Telo'), 
('Nelly'), 
('INNA'), 
('FARRUKO'), 
('Ciara'), 
('Trey Songz'), 
('kesha'), 
('Anitta'), 
('Tyga');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

SELECT f.musicNameFacebook
     , t.musicNameTwitter
     , y.musicNameYoutube
  FROM 
     ( SELECT musicNameFacebook musicName
         FROM facebookmusicstars 
        UNION
       SELECT musicNameTwitter
         FROM twittermusicstars 
        UNION
       SELECT musicNameYoutube
         FROM youtubemusicstars 
     ) x 
  LEFT
  JOIN facebookmusicstars f
    ON f.musicNameFacebook = x.musicName
  LEFT 
  JOIN twittermusicstars t
    ON t.musicNameTwitter  = x.musicName
  LEFT 
  JOIN youtubemusicstars y
    ON y.musicNameYoutube  = x.musicName;

+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
| musicNameFacebook | musicNameTwitter | musicNameYoutube |
+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
| Adele             | Adèle            | Adele            |
| AKON              | Akon             | Akon             |
| Anitta            | NULL             | Anitta           |
| Beyoncé           | Beyonce          | beyonce          |
| Bruno Mars        | NULL             | Bruno Mars       |
| Ciara             | NULL             | Ciara            |
| Drake             | Drake            | Drake            |
| Ed Sheeran        | NULL             | Ed Sheeran       |
| Eminem            | Eminem           | Eminem           |
| Farruko           | NULL             | FARRUKO          |
| Flo Rida          | NULL             | Flo Rida         |
| INNA              | NULL             | INNA             |
| Jason Derulo      | NULL             | Jason Derulo     |
| Kesha             | NULL             | kesha            |
| MALUMA            | NULL             | Maluma           |
| MattyBRaps        | NULL             | MattyBRaps       |
| Michel Teló       | NULL             | Michel Telo      |
| Nelly             | NULL             | Nelly            |
| Pitbull           | pitbull          | Pitbull          |
| Rihanna           | Rihanna          | NULL             |
| Shakira           | Shakira          | Shakira          |
| Trey Songz        | NULL             | Trey Songz       |
| Tyga              | Tyga             | Tyga             |
| Usher             | Usher            | Usher            |
| Wiz Khalifa       | NULL             | Wiz Khalifa      |
| NULL              | 50 Cent          | NULL             |
| NULL              | FettyWap         | NULL             |
| NULL              | Lil Wayne        | NULL             |
| NULL              | Ne-yo            | NULL             |
| NULL              | Snoop Dogg       | NULL             |
+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: The OP is trying to use `ON a.name <is similar too> b.name` because the names are slightly different in each table.  *(I didn't downvote)*

Comment: This is not what the OP intended , he needs to find a way to match words that are not 100% the same.

Comment: @sagi That's just a question of choosing the correct charset and collation. I don't think it's quite the drama you appear to imagine.

Comment: I didn't imagine any drama, just mentioned that your answer doesn't help the OP in achieving his goal, I'll cancel the down vote because of the comment you added, but I still think you should add more information to help him.

Comment: @sagi Yes I need to mach names somehow, but they are not same in all field. Some names have '@' , some have 'space' between names...and so on. The image I post show perfectly that where is null that name is not same like in other colums of tabel.

Comment: @NikicaAsanin I think that you will have to interfere your self, I don't think it can be achieve with SQL.

Comment: Please don't interfere yourself in my comments section.